# How do I format the data so that it will successfully post to the mongo DB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, react-hooks

So I am trying to build an app on react-native that takes variable workout data entered from a user and submits it to a mongo database. The information entered is the exercise name followed by an array containing the weight and number of reps. Below is the schema used.

```
    const exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema([{
    exerciseName: String,
    sets: [{
      weight: Number,
      reps: Number
    }]
  }]);
```

After data is collected, it is packaged and received in this format:

```
  [{"Seated Leg Extensions":
           [{"weight":"12","reps":"22"},
            {"weight":"12","reps":"2"}]},
      {"Shrugs":
           [{"weight":"12","reps":"33"}]
     }]
```

Should I either change the mongoose schema so that it may receive the code better **or** change the following code so that when it gets the object from the child component, it will manipulate the object so it matches the formatting of the original schema?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { View, ScrollView, Modal, Picker, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList  } from 'react-native';
import myExerciseList from './ExerciseList';
import {ExerciseView} from './Sets';

const exercises = myExerciseList

const ExerciseList = () => {

  const [dataFromChild, setDataFromChild] = useState([]);

  const handleChildData = (data) => {
    setDataFromChild([...dataFromChild, data]);
    console.log(dataFromChild)
  };

  const [views, setViews] = useState([]);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);

  //Form data to be sent to the database
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
    [{
      exerciseName: '',
      sets: [{
        weight: '',
        reps: ''
      }]
    }]
  )

  const handlePress = (item) => {
    setSelectedValue(item)
    const newView = <View  key={views.length} >
                      <Text>Exercise: {item.name}</Text>
                      <ExerciseView exerciseName={item.name} onData={handleChildData} ></ExerciseView>
                    </View>;
    setViews([...views, newView]);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const submitAll = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const dataSend = JSON.stringify(dataFromChild)
    console.log(dataSend)

    const updatedFormData = dataFromChild.map((exercise) => {
      const exerciseName = Object.keys(exercise)[0]
      const sets = exercise[exerciseName].map((set) => {
        return {
          weight: set.weight,
          reps: set.reps
        }
      })
      return {
        exerciseName,
        sets
      }
    })
    setFormData({
      exercises: updatedFormData
    })
    
    console.log(formData)
      
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/myworkouts', formData);
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    console.log(dataSend)
  }

  return ()

export default ExerciseList;
```

Finally, this is the router for posting the code to Mongo using express. I have confirmed that I am able to successfully connect to the database and pst data using POSTMAN.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Exercise = require('../models/workouts');

// Create a new exercise
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const exercise = new Exercise({
    exerciseName: req.body.exerciseName,
    sets: req.body.sets,  
    weight: req.body.weight,
    reps: req.body.reps,
  });
  try {
    const newExercise = await exercise.save();
    res.status(201).json(newExercise);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I would appreciate any help or criticism.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code `/api/v1/myworkouts` end-point code?

Comment: I just edited the original question to include the endpoint.